# Android app crash when call onPause

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onpause

Hello I am newish to android dev, I am using Eclipse and I have been developing some soundboards. my issue is this:

```
public class BernardsActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer eileanBeag;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bernards_layout);

        Button eileanBeagButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonB1);

        eileanBeagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                eileanBeag = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.eilean_beag);
                eileanBeag.start();
            }    
      });  

    ***public void onPause() {
        eileanBeag.release();                   
    }***    
}
```

the app works fine, all audio is playing well, but when I leave the app using the back button, it tells me that the process has stop unexpectedly and I have to force quit.

the method works fine when I define the MediaPlayer outside of the onCreate method, but I wish to use many sounds and to cut down on loading time I only define it once the button has been pushed.

I have tried using an OnCompleteListener and it does seem to work but then it cuts my sound clip off early.

so any help on this would be very much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: add try-catch block and try to find out what kind of exception it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that looks like a problem is,
before calling  `eileanBeag.release();` you should call `eileanBeag.stop();`. You cannot directly release a Player when you are playing. Also you are missing `super.onPause();`

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    eileanBeag.pause();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(eileanBeag != null) {
        eileanBeag.stop();  
        eileanBeag.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super.onPause()` as the first statement inside of your `onPause` method